# XMLRPC Python server

Tags: php, python, xml-rpc

I'm working on a project that has a XML-RPC PHP client connecting to a python server. I got the PHP client to work but don't know how the python server takes input parameters. From the PHP client we send a message with a string and two integer and want the python server to use those values to perform calculations.

How does XML-RPC servers in python take in values sent from the client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) for python implementation of this standard.

Here a server side example from there:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

def is_even(n):
    return n%2 == 0

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))
print "Listening on port 8000..."
server.register_function(is_even, "is_even")
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: xmlrpclib is only for the client side of XML-RPC

Comment: Funny, this is directly from the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html#boolean-objects). But it is a bad example. Remove the line `import xmlrpclib` because it is an unused import.

Comment: @ms4py you are right about the import I forgot about it and also mentioned that to be from there-- the link :D.